# symfony route not working but showing in console router:debug

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

I've added a route in my controller but it does not work even though i can see it in router:debug from the console.

```
/**
* @Route("/apilucky", name="lucky")
*/
public function numberAction(Request $request)
{
  // returns '{"username":"jane.doe"}' and sets the proper Content-Type header
    return $this->json(array('username' => 'jane.doe'));
}
```

I get a 404 message when i visit it from my browser or postman, but when I launch "php app/console router:debug " everything looks fine (carbon copy output from a existing/working route):

[not working route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tmFC.png)

[working route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6pn2.png)
(i had to do screenshots, formatting was not readable after copy/paste here)

I'm new to symfony but this looks like an easy fix. Did I forget to clear/refresh anything ? (I tried running "php app/console clear:cache" but it did not help).

---

edit:
Cache was cleared on client as well.

The address i'm trying to access is www.serverurl.fr/fr/apilucky

The controller file is huge (there is a ton of other routes (i did not set them up) that are working, but here's an extract:

```
<?php

namespace App\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class WebviewController extends BaseController
{
// ...
    /**
 * @Route("/accounts", name="accounts")
 */
public function AccountsAction(Request $request)
{
    $accounts = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppCoreBundle:Account')->findAll();
    $accountsArray = array();

    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
        $HasWeboob = $account->getWeboob();
        if ($HasWeboob) {
            $accountsArray[] = array(
                'id_weboob' => $account->getWeboob(),
                'account_name' => $account->getName(),
                'account_id' => $account->getId(),
                );
        }
    }
    return new JsonResponse($accountsArray);


 }
    /**
    * @Route("/apilucky", name="lucky")
    */
    public function numberAction(Request $request)
    {
      // returns '{"username":"jane.doe"}' and sets the proper Content-Type header
        return $this->json(array('username' => 'jane.doe'));
    }

}
```

---

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Julien

**SOLUTION:**

I cleared the cache on the server side and it worked. 
php app/console clear:cache --env=prod

Comment: Please share your controller code where you use the route.

Comment: Sorry, missed copy/paste. I've put it in the original message.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache? (command/manualy)

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access exactly and how is your webserver configured?

Comment: Do you have other route working in this controller ? Paste the whole controller could help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I did clear the cache and i tried to access /apilucky as url. I edited the orginal post with these info as well as the code for the controller.

Comment: What exactly does $this->json(array...) do?

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your help. I cleared the cache on the server side and it worked. php app/console clear:cache --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in the `@route` definition, you define your route in the controller as:

```
/**
* @Route("/apilucky", name="lucky")
*/
public function numberAction(Request $request)
{
  // your code here
}
```

But you are requesting `http://www.serverurl.fr/fr/apilucky` and the `locale` parameter doesn't exists in your route definition.

If request will be like `http://www.serverurl.fr/fr/apilucky` and also like `http://www.serverurl.fr/apilucky` you should to define your routes as:

```
/**
* @Route("/{_locale}/apilucky", name="lucky")
* @Route("/apilucky", name="otherLuckyName")
*/
public function numberAction(Request $request)
{
  // your code here
}
```

But if your request will be ever as `http://www.serverurl.fr/fr/apilucky` then you should define it as:

```
/**
* @Route("/{_locale}/apilucky", name="lucky")
*/
public function numberAction(Request $request)
{
  // your code here
}
```

Hope it helps.